# Multiplicity of root for $x^2 \sin(x^2) $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the function $x^2 \sin(x^2) $

How do I find the multiplicity of the root $x=0$?

What I've tried:
Differentiating, but this turns into a never ending mess.
How can be this be solved? (preferably without complex analysis)

Comment: Just use $\sin(x)=x+O(x^3)$ near $x=0$, so $x^2\sin(x^2)$ behaves like $x^4$.

Comment: What about $\sin(t)\sim t$ ?

Comment: Can multiplicity be defined for anything but a polynomial?

Comment: @BernardMassé It's an analytic entire function, so the concept makes full sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the power series definition of sine:
$$x^2\sin x^2=x^2\Bigl(x^2-\frac{x^6}6+\frac{x^{10}}{120}-\dotsm\Bigr)=x^4-\frac{x^8}6+\frac{x^{12}}{120}-\dotsm$$
so the order of multiplicity is $4$.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of multiplicity of a root makes sense for analytic functions; in this case, it's the unique positive integer $k$ such that
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^k}
$$
exists (finite) and is $\ne0$.

In your case,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin(x^2)}{x^4}=1
$$